# Setting login shell in SSS configuration for users from Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, domain, sssd

I'm trying to define different login shells for different users of an AD domain, [as described here](https://serverfault.com/questions/577345/sssd-is-there-a-way-to-force-a-specific-shell-for-some-group-members). The aim is to deny members of a particular group from logging in while allowing them to do SSH tunneling.

Here below is the file `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`. MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL is the default domain provided by the AD. The config below defines a test domain MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL, which is not in the AD, as the domain for these limited  users. (This is just a configuration for testing: later, in the MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL domain section, `override_shell = /bin/zsh` will be replaced by `override_shell = /sbin/nologin`.)

```
[sssd]
domains = MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL,MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[nss]
default_shell = /bin/bash

[domain/MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL]
ad_server = ad.mydomain.global
ad_domain = MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL
ldap_user_search_filter = (memberOf=CN=AdminsGroup,OU=Groups,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=GLOBAL)
id_provider = ad
simple_allow_groups = AdminsGroup@MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL
override_shell = /bin/bash

[domain/MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL]
ad_server = ad.mydomain.global
ad_domain = MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL
ldap_user_search_filter = (memberOf=CN=LimitedGroup,OU=Groups,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=GLOBAL)
id_provider = ad
simple_allow_groups = LimitedGroup@MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL
override_shell = /bin/zsh
```

A member of MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL is able to login via SSH, while a member of MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL can't and gets a "Permission denied, please try again" or a "Authentication failed" error.

The `sssd` logfiles don't show any error.

Why is that?

Does MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL need to be present in the AD? If yes, is it possible to somehow bypass this and configure sss with different "local categories" of users to do what I want?

(Note: Apparently this can be done with nlscd, as [per this question](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/changing-the-shell-for-users-on-ldap-auth-server-4175501977/) and [this other question](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=46386), but it requires a LDAP server, and configuring it to use an AD is another can of worms.)

Comment: In the `MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL` definition block do you really intend to compare against groups within `MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL` rather than `MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL`? Similarly, does the `ad.mydomain.global` AD server really serve the `MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL` domain?

Comment: Oops, you're right. Fixed typo.

Comment: The `MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL` does not exist in the AD, is only defined here in the SSS config. I'd like to know if this would work.

Comment: A similar question over on SF https://serverfault.com/q/928369/267016 might get you some possible answers

Comment: Does it work using `ldap_user_search_base` instead?

Comment: If you can make this work, how do you plan to use it to restrict users to ssh tunnels, and deny them a shell? (i'm curious)

Comment: What version of sssd do you use?

Comment: @ChristopheDrevet-Droguet It's sssd 1.16.0-19.el7_5.5.  By setting the user login shell to /sbin/nologin or /bin/false, the user can perform a SSH tunnel but not a SSH login, I've tested.

Comment: Nice. That's good to know.

Comment: One has just to use SSH with the `-N` option (no shell) and the `-L` option (tunneling), see https://serverfault.com/questions/56566/ssh-tunneling-only-access and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100859/ssh-tunnel-without-shell-on-ssh-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the [sssd maintainers](https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd/) I found the answer. Here's a working config which does what I needed, i.e. allow SSH tunneling but not SSH login to the AD users which are members of the AD LimitedGroup.

Note that a member of the limited group must ssh as `user@MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL`, not as `user@MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL`, or it won't work.

The gist of the solution is in using the SSSD section domain name instead of the AD domain name in the `simple_allow_groups` directive. Note, however, that the config also works without the lines `access_provider = simple` and `simple_allow_groups = ...`. It is also possible to set `simple_allow_groups = group` without the `use_fully_qualified_names = True` directive, as reported by an user in the comments.

Also, note that this config uses `ldap_user_search_base` instead of the deprecated `ldap_user_search_filter`.

The other configuration options are only for completeness as they were already in the config file.

```
[sssd]
domains = MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL,MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[nss]
default_shell = /bin/bash

[domain/MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL]
ldap_user_search_base = DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=GLOBAL?subtree?(memberOf=CN=LimitedGroup,OU=Groups,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=GLOBAL)
default_shell = /sbin/nologin
ad_server = ad.mydomain.global
ad_backup_server = ad2.mydomain.global
ad_domain = MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL
krb5_realm = MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
cache_credentials = False
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = LimitedGroup@MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL

[domain/MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL]
ldap_user_search_base = DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=GLOBAL?subtree?(memberOf=CN=AdminsGroup,OU=Groups,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=GLOBAL)
default_shell = /bin/bash
ad_server = ad.mydomain.global
ad_backup_server = ad2.mydomain.global
ad_domain = MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL
krb5_realm = MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
cache_credentials = False
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = AdminsGroup@MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL
```

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. I just don't understand why you have to add these `simple` access directives while I don't. I really use my actual answer in my environment.

Comment: It could be the use of `access_provider = simple` with `simple_allow_groups = group@DOMAIN` instead of `simple_allow_groups = group` (the latter seems to work for me) without the `use_fully_qualified_names = True` directive. I don't use access directives at all, as the `ldap_user_search_base` should just return the selected accounts anyway. Another thing: if you use `use_fully_qualified_names = True`, you must connect with `ssh -l user@MYDOMAIN_TEST.GLOBAL myserver` to use the right sssd domain, don't you? "If set to TRUE, all requests to this domain must use fully qualified names" tells man.

Comment: I just tested and you're right, these 2 config lines are not needed. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Cool. I think we have reached some mutual understanding of this configuration. Thank you for the bounty, too.

Answer (score 3):

This should work with newer versions of sssd:

```
[sssd]
domains = MYDOMAIN_ADMINS,MYDOMAIN_LIMITED,MYDOMAIN_ALL
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[nss]
default_shell = /bin/bash

[domain/MYDOMAIN_ADMINS]
ad_server = srv001.company.local,srv002.company.local,srv003.company.local,srv004.company.local
ad_domain = company.local  
ldap_user_search_base = DC=company,DC=local?subtree?(memberOf=CN=unix_admins,OU=Groupes,OU=Main Office,DC=company,DC=local)
id_provider = ad
override_shell = /usr/bin/pwd
override_homedir = /home/%u

[domain/MYDOMAIN_LIMITED]
ad_server = srv001.company.local,srv002.company.local,srv003.company.local,srv004.company.local
ad_domain = company.local  
ldap_user_search_base = DC=company,DC=local?subtree?(memberOf=CN=unix_limited,OU=Groupes,OU=Main Office,DC=company,DC=local)
id_provider = ad
override_shell = /usr/bin/date
override_homedir = /home/%u

[domain/MYDOMAIN_ALL]
ad_server = srv001.company.local,srv002.company.local,srv003.company.local,srv004.company.local
ad_domain = company.local  
ldap_user_search_base = DC=company,DC=local
id_provider = ad
override_homedir = /home/%u
```

The `ldap_user_search_base` is used instead of the now deprecated (removed?) `ldap_user_search_filter`.

I don't know if adding a `simple_allow_groups` with a `ldap_user_search_base` filter is correct or not. I wonder if it would work with only a `simple_allow_groups` directive.

Comment: I've tested, it does not work because `[domain/MYDOMAIN_ADMINS]` and `[domain/MYDOMAIN_LIMITED]` are defined in sssd only and not in the AD.  A sssd section `[domain/MYDOMAIN.GLOBAL]` works because this matches the AD domain.  But thanks for the effort.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. The sssd domain name has *nothing* to do with the actual AD domain name. It's working for me with a brand new CentOS 7.5. I'll update my answer with my exact configuration.

Comment: What you say makes sense, however as a matter of fact this config does not work.  I would be very happy if you prove me wrong, as my issue would then be solved :)

Comment: I understand your frustration. There must be some other issue at stake. What happens if you bypass authentication entirely, by using `su - auser` with root? Do you have more info in the system authentification log?

Comment: Someone helped me in finding a solution, see my answer. I marked it as "accepted" for future readers because I verified it works for me, but I have rewarded your good answer with the bounty.